# Conditional formatting for cells that have date/time within the last 24 hours

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google sheet that has a column for "last updated" and each row represents a separate file. People manually paste in the time and date in that column, like in the screenshot.

If the date and time *is not* within the last 24 hours, then I want that cell to turn red. The "date is before" option only checks the date and not the time.

For this example, let's say the current time is 930 AM, so the cells that have a time *before* 9:30 AM yesterday should turn red. The cells that have a time *after* 9:30 AM yesterday should remain unaffected.

This is what I want it to look like.

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

How can I do this with Google Sheets conditional formatting?

Here is my test sheet.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DRQYrxpE61e7VMEpbuiCO543cpZvcckVr0PKPnQcPw4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *...say the current time is 930am, so the cells that have a time BEFORE 9:30am yesterday should turn red. The cells that have a time AFTER 9:30am yesterday should remain unaffected.*

There is a setting to choose so, right from within the conditional format menu.

For your chosen range you pick the
setting **`Is between`** and as values **`=NOW()-2`** and **`=NOW()-1`**

[image: Conditional formatting for cells that have date/time within the last 24 hours]

Comment: thanks for trying! tho this option only looks at the date and not the time. So if the current time was 12am on 02/14 it would still mark 11pm on 2/13 as red even tho it was only an hour ago. I need it to check it it has not been withing 24 hours.

Comment: I don't think so. It looks at both the date and time. Have you tried it? In case you still have issues, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DRQYrxpE61e7VMEpbuiCO543cpZvcckVr0PKPnQcPw4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you @marikamitsos!

Comment: You were right. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes! thank you! it worked!!

Comment: Glad I could help. :) And thank you for making me take a second look to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks a little complicated in Google Sheets, but the formatting for a query that you could use in the conditional formatting is here: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/datetime-in-query-in-google-sheets/

Comment: Ive been trying since your answer but i still cant get it right :( Should i use "exact formal" in Conditional Formatting? Or should i use "Date is before" and "exact date"?

Comment: Here is my test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DRQYrxpE61e7VMEpbuiCO543cpZvcckVr0PKPnQcPw4/edit?usp=sharing